# Force browser to download any file (S3 Amazon) instead of opening in browser it angular 5

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

```
  <a  [href]="url+selected.file.filename" target="_blank" download mat-icon-button class="" aria-label="Download" matTooltip="Download">
      <mat-icon>file_download</mat-icon>
  </a>
```

when I click link, file show in browser instead of download. please help me

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileSaver.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) for angular. FileSaver.js implements the saveAs() FileSaver interface in browsers that do not natively support it.

Comment: I download a file S3 amazon. can you give me example S3 amazon download file?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you might be able to change MIME type of the file to something appropriate. Having the wrong MIME type will have you download the files instead of viewing it in your browser. This is a popular problem with S3 hosted files. To fix go to S3 > your bucket > your directory > your file > properties > change mime type to the appropriate one.

Your type will probably be "application/octet-stream" which means S3 didn't recognize the media type. This is normally the incorrect type, but it might work here.

Btw - this is normally done in the reverse so files *won't* be downloaded.

Comment: I say Force browser to download any file (S3 Amazon) instead of opening in browser